# R: Sorting in ggplot2 legend with manipulate()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get a strange behaviour in the legent of a ggplot using scale_colour_discrete. The labels are number that should be sorted by default. However here the sorting occur in an weird way, see MWE:

```
require(ggplot2)
val <- data.frame("x" = c(15,15,15,15,20,20,20,20), 
                "label" = c(150,100,50,10,150,100,50,10), 
                "y" = c(23,26,43,32,45,32,12,25))

manipulate(
  {
  gg <- ggplot(val, aes(group=label, colour=factor(label)))

  if(p150){ gg <- gg + geom_line(data=val[val$label==150,], aes(x = x, y = y))}

  if(p100){ gg <- gg + geom_line(data=val[val$label==100,], aes(x = x, y = y))}

  if(p50){gg <- gg + geom_line(data=val[val$label==50,], aes(x = x, y = y))}

  if(p10){gg <- gg + geom_line(data=val[val$label==10,], aes(x = x, y = y))}

  gg
  },

  p150 = checkbox(TRUE,"150"),  # Add buttons
  p100 = checkbox(TRUE,"100"),
  p50 = checkbox(TRUE,"50"),
  p10 = checkbox(TRUE,"10")
)
```

[image]

Any idea of the cause?

**EDIT:** As I add each line conditionnally, I have to declare each geom_line separately, as shown in the example.

Comment: Could you post a picture also?

Comment: `ggplot2` uses factors to sort by

Comment: Sorry I need 10 reputation to post an image :-/

Comment: The manual subsetting you do is unnecessary. If you do `ggplot(val, aes(x=x,y=y,group=label, col=factor(label))) + geom_line()`, the correct factor is generated.

Comment: Someone can edit your post to include it

Comment: @Heroka you're right, but the problem is that in my main code I'm adding each line conditionnally in a "manipulate" command. I'll add this the question.

Comment: @JohnBee Can you clarify why you need to call separate `geom_line`? If the legend is being added from the label anyway, then why wouldn't Heroka's suggestion work for you? Perhaps you could consider creating a new variable to group and colour? The way you are doing it, the legend is being sorted alphabetically (not numerically).

Comment: It can be solved by `gg + scale_color_discrete(limits=rev(unique(val$label)),name="label")`, but have a hunch we're trying to fix the wrong kind of problem here. But maybe that's me; I generally prefer to separate data-manipulation (summarizing, selection) and plotting.

Comment: @Heroka Thanks, that solved it! Can you post it as an answer so that I can validate your input? I'm editing the question to add details about lines separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gg + scale_color_discrete(limits=rev(unique(val$label)),name="label")
```